# How to query the mongoDB admin database?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to execute the below commands taken from the [mongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#mongodb-2-4-user-model-removed)

```
use admin
db.system.version.find( { _id: "authSchema" })
```

But running those in Robo 3t gives the following output

```
switched to db admin

Error: error: { 
"$err" : "not authorized for query on admin.system.version", "code" : 13 
}
```

The user I'm logged in with has the [dbOwner role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbOwner).

Some people suggest granting the root role to the user, but this fails, saying 'not authorized'

```
db.grantRolesToUser(
    "fooUser",
    [ "readWrite" , { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
)
```

It seems like a bad idea to grant root access just for this one query anyways, but I don't see any better solution.

So, how does one query the admin database in mongoDB?

(Current mongoDB version is 2.6.11)

Comment: The dbOwner role will only grant permissions on a single database. If the user is a dbOwner on `foo`, it will be able to create other users that can read `foo`, but will not be able to grant permissions on the `admin` database. You will need a user with permissions on admin to grant a role to your user.

Answer (score 1):

As per your log statement you are getting the error message such as

```
Error: error: { 
"$err" : "not authorized for query on admin.system.version", "code" : 13 
}
```

As github mongodb documentation [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/base/error_codes.err) **`error_code("Unauthorized", 13)`**.

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#read) MongoDB grants access to data and commands through [role-based authorization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/#roles) and provides built-in roles that provide the different levels of access commonly needed in a database system. You can additionally create [user-defined roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/#user-defined-roles).

A role grants privileges to perform sets of [actions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#security-user-actions) on defined [resources](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/resource-document/#resource-document). A given role applies to the database on which it is defined and can grant access down to a collection level of granularity.

You need to assign the `read` role or `readWrite` to the user.

For example :

***Create Administrative User with Roles***

```
use admin
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "appAdmin",
     pwd: "password",
     roles:
       [
         { role: "readWrite", db: "config" }

       ]
   }
)
```

For further your ref [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27027?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true), [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbOwner) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619018/mongodb-not-authorized-for-query-code-13)